# How to send AWS cloudwatch logs to AWS redshift automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to AWS. My requirement is, I need to send AWS cloudwatch logs automatically to AWS redshift. Is it possible throught Lambda script? Is there any other option available for this?

Comment: Do you want it to happen in _near real-time_ or will that export run as a scheduled job?

Comment: near real-time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cloudwatch event rule as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html 
At the target you can't choose Redshift directly, so first you have to send your logs to a lambda and then use some logic to load it to redshift. 
My recomendation is this case would be doing this operation through Kinesis Firehose and S3.

The data flow would look like this:
Cloudwatch Events Rule > Lambda > Firehose > S3 > Redshift.

Comment: You can now go direct from Cloudwatch to Firehose via the Cloudwatch subscription filter example outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample